# kill the deadlock

Tags: java, android, multithreading, deadlock

i'm currently (trying) to program a little game. And i have a small design/deadlock issue.

When i press a button, a new Intent opens and surfaceDestroyed sets a boolean to set the thread sleeping.
When i return the thread gets a notify signal.

This works in about 90% of the time (and 100% when i debug with eclipse).

I believe the deadlock takes place in the run function of the thread (two synchronized). The problem is, wait() needs a synchronized of the thread and ondraw() needs the lock on the surfaceholder.

I played already around a bit, but all other combinations makes everything worse, and i dont know how to solve this. So please help :)

The Thread:

```
class BattleEarthThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private BattleEarthView _battleEarthView;
    private boolean _run = false;
    private boolean _suspended = false;

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return _surfaceHolder;
    }

    public BattleEarthThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, BattleEarthView panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _battleEarthView = panel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    public void setSuspend(boolean suspend) {
        _suspended = suspend;
    }

    public boolean getSuspended() {
        return _run;
    }

    public boolean getRunning() {
        return _run;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        _run = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                        c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                        synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {

                            if(_suspended)
                                this.wait();

                            else {
                                _battleEarthView.onDraw(c);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see the other thread's code to fully understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
synchronized(this) {
    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
    synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {

        if(_suspended)
            this.wait();

        else {
            _battleEarthView.onDraw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

You're taking out two locks - `this` and `_surfaceHolder`. You're then *releasing* the lock on `this` by calling `wait`... but you still own the lock for `_surfaceHolder`.

Now suppose another thread executes the same code on the same object. It manages to acquire the lock for `this`, because nothing else owns it at the moment... but it blocks when trying to acquire `_surfaceHolder`, because the waiting thread owns it.

At this point, you're stuffed:

- No thread can acquire the lock on the object being waited on, because the second thread owns it
- Even if another thread *could* pulse that lock, the waiting thread would still need to reacquire the lock on `this` before continuing, which it won't be able to

So basically you've got two threads, each of which owns one lock and is waiting for something impossible to happen. It's not *quite* the normal deadlock (where each thread owns one lock and is waiting for the other's) but it's pretty close.

Moral: don't call `wait()` on a thread which currently "owns" more monitors than the one it's about to call `wait()` on.

Comment: i thought so, but how to get rid of the problem? notify needs the lock on the thread an ondraw needs the surfaceholder?

Comment: @user989349: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, to be honest. But eek - I hadn't seen that you were locking on a *thread* reference. Firstly, don't extend Thread - implement Runnable instead. Secondly, don't acquire the lock on a Thread or wait on it. Other things do that, so it's best not to do it yourself. What's pulsing the lock, and could it pulse `_surfaceHolder` instead?

Comment: to clarify things up: I have a Map and when i click on a town i want to build something. When i exit the town the Map should be shown again. so the first part for the map drawing is from LunarLander (there is also a thread) the second part is from Oracle (search for threadPrimitiveDeprecation :) )

Comment: @user989349: I'm afraid that doesn't clarify much - what do you mean by "the second part is from Oracle"?

Comment: Sorry first time to write stuff on stackoverflow so much editing here. Well i don't want the thread to draw the map, when i don't need it. I wanted to stop the thread from drawing. So i searched for Thread stopping and found: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: @user989349: I strongly suspect you're going about things the wrong way, to be honest. You should only be drawing in the UI thread, not some arbitrary other thread - and then you should only draw the things you need, which you can check with clipping etc. I suspect you need to fundamentally redesign your approach, I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't mind redesigning everything, still learning in the android dev :) - then another question, will the thread still draw in the background, when another activity and Surface is active? Or a better question, how can i stop him from doing so?

Comment: @Christian: You shouldn't be *trying* to draw on the UI in a background thread - drawing should be performed on the UI thread. If you need something to periodically update, use a timer on the UI thread. At least, that's assuming Android UIs work the same way as all the other UI frameworks I've used. (I haven't written any Android code myself.)

Comment: I don't want to draw in a background thread, thats why i want to suspend it. And thats why i ran in the problem mentioned. And i can't redesign when i don't know how to do it better :) (ill take a look at Runnable). But your input gave me an idea: i'm synchronizing now only one at a time and draw or suspend it. It currently seems to work.

Comment: @Christian: Ideally, don't synchronize at all. Why do you actually need background threads here in the first place?

Comment: I honestly didn't actually thought about why i need a thread. But everybody (tutorials, LunarLander) does it so i did it too.

After a little research i stumbled across http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html#on-surfaceview